# Is the Door To Nowhere important, or is it an easter egg?

Tags: dishonored

In Piero's office, there's a readable note that talks about his "Door to Nowhere" invention.

Near the stairs, there's a doorway with a symbol on it that looks *suspiciously* like the Portal logo.

[image: Portal Logo]

**Is this important to the game, an easter egg, or just a coincidence?**

Comment: Pretty sure it's just an easter egg, but I could see it used as the access point for some future DLC (*fingers crossed*) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acheivement Hunter called it an Easter Egg, so I guess there is nothing more to this than what is shown in this video.